# How to make testing script click or select tree menu expand icon on selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a question on selenium ide testing. How should I click or select on tree menu expand icon? When an icon hasn't any id or text, only class. `<div class="GridxTreeExpandoIcon">` and it also has a shortcut control + right arrow. How to can I click control and right arrow with this script?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the class as a locator to target the click, it would just be:

```
class=GridxTreeExpandoIcon
```

Or if you needed to be more specific and reference the div (if the same class is used for multiple elements:

```
css=div[class="GridxTreeExpandoIcon"]
```

This second version can be used for any attribute within a tag (e.g. title, value etc.)

Comment: Maybe You could tell me how to click that icon, which is near some text. To be clear, there are few GirdxTreeExpandoIcons. And every icon is near some component id. For example near component id 1 : `<div class="gridxTreeExpandoContent gridxCellContent">1<\div>`